# how to properly import files in python3

Tags: python-3.x, python-import, importerror

I have my files like this:

```
main.py
folder/
    __init__.py
    file_to_import.py
    other_file_used_by_file_to_import.py
```

I get a ModuleNotFoundError when I use `import folder.file_to_import`

then I tried `from .file_to_import import function` then I get a

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.admin_menu'; '__main__' is not a package`

can't seem to be able to find who to do this properly in python3.

Comment: Show how you're running this, I suspect you should be using [`python -m module`](https://github.com/asottile/scratch/wiki/PythonPathSadness) instead of `python file.py`.

Comment: But I want to run the code in file.py and use certain functions from module. I use a bash script to activate my virtual env and run the python inside the virtual env

Comment: If you show how you're invoking things in the question we can tell you how to import *and* how to use the commandline in your bash script